# Swift CoreData DictionaryResultType cast

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, swift

in the following code I use CoreData to get distinct results:

```
    request.propertiesToFetch = NSArray(objects: "docID", "docName")
    request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
    request.returnsDistinctResults = true

    var distinctResults: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)
    println(distinctResults)
```

This is the output of println():

> (
>           {
>           docID = 3;
>           docName = "Dr. Goy";
>       },
>           {
>           docID = 1;
>           docName = "Dr. Bar";
>       },
>           {
>           docID = 0;
>           docName = "Dr. Foo";
>       },
>           {
>           docID = 2;
>           docName = "Mr. Baz";
>       }
>   )

It's an Array with Dictionaries - How I can cast this NSArray into a Dictionary with a for loop

Thanks for help!

Comment: What format do you want the dictionary to be in?

Comment: Sorry - I want to cast to Dictionary<Int, String>

Answer (score 5):

An NSArray can be used as an Array, it's more complicated because the structure of your response isn't `Array<Dictionary<Int,String>>`, it's really `Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>` where Any is String for docName, but int for docID.

```
var dict = Dictionary<Int, String>()
for nsdict in distinctResults as Array<NSDictionary> {
    let docId = nsdict.valueForKey("docID") as? NSNumber as? Int
    let docName = nsdict.valueForKey("docName") as? String

    if docId && docName {
        dict[docId!] = docName!
    }
}
```